# Batch rename multiple files by creation date

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, batch-rename

this is my first question in superuser.
As you probably read in the title I would like to rename multiple files using a .bat file.
I'm currently working on a project that involves books. In this case is important keep book chapters separate and named correctly, I have, for example 3 files in the same directory that are 3 chapters:

`example.pdf` created at 16:44 PM
`anotherexample.pdf` created at 16:45 PM
`thelastexample.pdf` created at 16:46 PM

I would like to rename them with a sequence of increasing numbers from 0 (0, 1, 2) in this case, but assigning numbers according to the **date of creation**.

So they can become:

`1.pdf` created at 16:44 PM
`2.pdf` created at 16:45 PM
`3.pdf` created at 16:46 PM

How can I do this using a batch file or a cmd command?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, thanks for the suggestion, I will do it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this batch script:

```
@echo off

:: Put the path to the folder where the files should be renamed here:
set Folder=%userprofile%\desktop\Folder

For /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /od /tc /a-d /b "%Folder%"') do call :Rename "%%a" "%%~nxa"
exit

:Rename
set /a Counter+=1
ren "%Folder%\%~1" "%Counter% %~2"
goto :EOF
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using powershell:

```
$i=0;dir|sort CreationTime|%{$i++;ren "$($_.fullname)" -newn {$i+$_.extension}}
```